# How to disable administrative share C$ only to some computers or users

Tags: windows-7, blocking

In my network the users can acces with the administrative share C$ to my computer because they are admin users, is possible to block some computers or users? 
I tried to change some options with firewall but I couldn't get.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a local admin, you can simply remove Domain Admins from the local Administrators group on your PC.  That will block other users with Admin rights from getting to your C$ share, but you could still get to it if you wanted.